# Meaning of "She bade me know"

Tags: meaning

I'm studying a text for translation and I'm unsure about my reading of the following paragraph.

> I asked Nuit to write the rituals, the ordeals, and the law.
>
> She bade me know that the ordeals may not be written, since each man
>   must go through a furnace of his own kindling. The Rituals: some were
>   fitted for all men: some are fitted to one person, each making his
>   own; and also there are those whose virtue lies in the silence
>   wherewith they are begirt.

I understand "bid" here is not "offer" but "ask", in general. But I can't go any more specific than that. What does "she bade me know" means?

Comment: It's *ask*, but more in the sense of [*entreat*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/entreat), yet not to the point of pleading.

Comment: That writer is intending to sound archaic by using "bade".  (Even more "begirt".)  So to make a good translation you will need not only to know the meanings, but also to write this in an archaic form of your own language.

Answer (score 2):

**bade**  [MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/bid_1)

> past tense    **bid or bade** past participle bidden [transitive]
>   literary: **to order** someone to do something

and [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bade):

> to command; order; direct:

As in:

"She bade me know ..." or "She ordered/commanded/directed me to know that the ordeals may not be written."

Comment: I think some more is needed here. "Bade' COULD mean "ordered" if the bidder were a superior fully authorized to give orders. Generally the word follows the older definitions of "pray" or "ask" (Anglo-Saxon "bidden")